# Finding the UTF8 character of bytes (represented in hex)

Tags: swift, unicode, utf-8

[I already know](https://unicode-table.com/en/2014/) that the code point *U+2014* in Unicode is encoded in UTF8 as *E2 80 94* hex

I want to see the character in UTF8.

I did two trials, and both give the same error:

#### First try

```
let bytes = [UInt8("94", radix: 16), UInt8("80", radix: 16), UInt8("E2", radix: 16) ]
let value = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

#### Second try

```
let bytes = [0x94, 0x80, 0x16]
let value = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

My playground gives this error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:7:13: error: generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred
let value = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

P.S. I already tried to swap the hex values from left to right but I still get the same error.

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second try works fine once you specify that it's an array of `UInt8`.

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0xE2, 0x80, 0x94]
let value = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

It's also helps to put the correct values in the array - E2, 80, 94, not 94, 80, 16.

Comment: Indeed specifying the type explicitly solves the problem. Thank you

Comment: And the solution for the first try is *let bytes = [UInt8("E2", radix: 16)!, UInt8("80", radix: 16)!, UInt8("94", radix: 16)! ]* I need to unwrap the optional

Comment: The 2nd approach is much better than the 1st since the 1st requires a lot of string parsing at runtime while the 2nd has no runtime requirement.

Comment: Agree, though I do use numbering system with radix different than 16